# Programmatically change sharing for google files based on data in the files

Tags: google-apps-script, sharing

I have a directory in Google drive with about 30 spreadsheets. Each spreadsheet will have an email address in a set location (for example, cell A1).

I would like to create a script that will go through each file in that directory and give viewing rights for that file only to the email address listed in the file.

Can someone help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's pseudocode that will accomplish your task, with links to relevant documentation.

- Get all spreadsheet files in the directory

  1. [DocsList.getFolder(path)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/docs-list#getFolder%28String%29)
  2. [Folder.getFilesByType(type)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/folder#getFilesByType%28FileType%29), where type = DocsList.[FileType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file-type).SPREADSHEET.
- Loop over all those files, and set permissions

  1. Get the embedded email address

     - [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app).openById([file.getId()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/docs-list/file#getId%28%29)).getRange("A1").getValue()
  2. Share spreadsheet with that user.

     - [Spreadsheet.addViewer](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addViewer%28User%29)(emailAddress)